# AFNetworking error parsing JSON

Tags: json, cocoa, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking 2.3 API to fetch currency exchange rates which returns JSON. In addition to HTTP the API also supports HTTPS. I'm using a subclass of AFHTTPSessionManager and set the response serializer to AFJSONResponseSerializer.

If I use HTTP everything works as expected, however once I use HTTPS, I receive the following error

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The data couldn’t be read
>   because it isn’t in the correct format." (JSON text did not start with
>   array or object and option to allow fragments not set.)
>   UserInfo=0x60000046c700 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

I checked the response data and it appears identical to the HTTP response.  Also the response code is 200 and the header indicates

> "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

If I entry the url directly into safari the data appears as expected. I also tried setting the reading options of the response serializer to NSJSONReadingAllowFragments, but no change.

Is this a server side issue? What else could I do to debug this?

Comment: Put the response that fails into a JSON validator. That will be  the fastest way to see if the JSON is valid.

Comment: Write HTTP response to a file and write the HTTPS a separate file. Use a diff utility to compare the files: that will show you the differences.

Comment: @JefferyThomas I put the HTTPS URL in a browser and and used a JSON validator and it is valid. Not sure how I would write the HTTPS to a file since the response serializer returns nil when an error is present. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: `-[AFJSONResponseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:data:error:]` in `AFURLResponseSerialization.m` is where I would start. It has the raw response.